# Squirrel SQL Error Code 102

Tags: sql

I'm very confused - I opened up my database in Squirrel SQL to do some SQL and I type this in my SQL entry window:

```
select * from *
```

And for whatever reason it gives me this output:

```
Error: Incorrect syntax near '*'.
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 102
```

Does anyone know what this means? It's hard to do a google search because Google treats the asterisk as a special character.

Comment: -1 for apparently not looking into the database's SQL reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that second `*` is invalid, that should be a table name:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the table name.

```
  SELECT * FROM myTable
```

If however you knew that and you are actually looking for a way to `SELECT` from all your tables i'm afraid you'll have to type them one by one like this :

```
   SELECT * FROM myTable1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM myTable2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM myTable3
   ...
```

Also remember that if you have to Select like I did on the second example, there is a problem with the way your data is organized in you database. If it's the case, you should take a look at [this article on Data Normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm).